# Exibir array durante o debug com android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, jni

No android, ao debugar meu programa consigo ver o vetor e o conteúdo dele:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho que passar esse vetor do android (java) para C++ e estou usando NDK.

```
public native void testeVetor(double[] vetorDados);
testeVetor(vetorDados);
```

testeVetor é uma função no C++:

[image: Função no C++]

Atualmente quando eu debugo, quando chega no C++, ele mostra o vetor dessa forma:
[image: Só mostra a primeira posição do vetor]

Minha dúvida é: quando eu tiver debugando, como eu posso exibir o vetor no C++ assim como é exibido no java?